# Keep the popover in the same position when zooming in the map with Bootstrap 4 and OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, bootstrapping

I tried the popover example from the OpenLayers web site: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html

It works very well but when I change the version of Bootstrap to version 4 and jQuery to version 3.3.1 the popover change the location when I zoom on the map.

I want to keep the popover in the position that I clicked even when I zoom.